# Elastic search bulk write requests end up on the same node from the cluster, causing the cluster to reject writes

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-storm

I have an ElasticSearch 2.1.1 cluster with 11 nodes.
Most of the time everything goes well, but when the load increases (writing data from multiple Storm topologies) it seems that all the write requests go to the same node and end up with a node overworked with his queue over the limit, while other nodes are just siting there doing nothing.

```
node bulk.active bulk.queue
1       0           0
2       0           0
3       32          114
4       0           0
.and so on
```

And after a while the cluster starts to reject the write requests:

```
 nested: EsRejectedExecutionException[rejected execution
of org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryPhase$1@7e368c0b on EsThreadPoolExecutor[bulk, queue capacity = 50, org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsThreadPoolExecutor@13ff1612[Running, pool size = 32, active threads = 32, queued tasks =
 55, completed tasks = 249363622]
```

After the load passes it recovers, but the same thing happens each time the load increases.

Has anyone encountered something like this? What might be the cause?

Comment: 2 things, first. you say your Elasticsearch version 2.2? second, what happens when the load is average or normal? do the other nodes get the write requests?

Comment: First, good point, actually it is 2.1.1, sorry for the mistake, Second: it seems that yes they get some writes requests, when checking the thread_pool.bulk info I see different completed and rejected on different nodes.

Comment: Are there any storm logs on the nimbus or supervisors that are helpful?